# Get specific JSON data from JSON array

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON array that is converted from XML and i'd like to know how I can get parts of that JSON.

From another answer i've found

```
var result =
 JObject.Parse(jsonResult).Children().Children().Children().ElementAt(1).Children().First();
```

but that just gets me one part of the JSON and isn't very easy to figure out how to then get other parts.

This is the part I get from the code above

```
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
```

This is the JSON

```
{
      "soap12:Envelope": {
        "@xmlns:soap12": "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope",
        "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
        "@xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
        "soap12:Body": {
          "ProcessRequestResponse": {
            "@xmlns": "http://localhost/TestServices",
            "ProcessRequestResult": {
              "StatusCode": "None or GE or PE or PW or NP or FS or NA or GF",
              "Success": "boolean",
              "Errors": {
                "Error": [
                  {
                    "Code": "int",
                    "ErrorText": "string",
                    "ErrorType": "None or Critical or Non_Critical",
                    "Severity": "Warning or Error"
                  },
                  {
                    "Code": "int",
                    "ErrorText": "string",
                    "ErrorType": "None or Critical or Non_Critical",
                    "Severity": "Warning or Error"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I would like to be able to get "StatusCode" or "Success" or anything in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend not using `JObject.Parse` directly and instead deserialise directly to your own class hierarchy. For example, with a simple set of classes like this:

```
public class SoapObject
{
    [JsonProperty("soap12:Envelope")]
    public SoapData Envelope { get; set; }
}

public class SoapData
{
    [JsonProperty("soap12:Body")]
    public SoapBody Body { get; set; }
}

public class SoapBody
{
    public ProcessRequestResponse ProcessRequestResponse { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessRequestResponse
{
    public ProcessRequestResult ProcessRequestResult { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessRequestResult
{
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Success { get; set; }
}
```

You could deserialise simply:

```
var soapObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SoapObject>(jsonResult);
```

And now you have strongly typed access to the properties you need:

```
var statusCode = soapObject.Envelope.Body
    .ProcessRequestResponse.ProcessRequestResult.StatusCode;
```

Comment: Spot on, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

DavidG answer is good enough but in case you want to know how to access json data then use `JObject`

```
        var jo = JObject.Parse(myJsonString);
        var status = jo["soap12:Envelope"]["Success"];
```

Namespace is `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;`

Comment: I did try something like this but didn't have much luck. Had a go with your example but i'm getting nothing back unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

To get them with JObject.Parse()

```
string jsonresult = "{\"soap12:Envelope\":{\"@xmlns:soap12\":\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\",\"@xmlns:xsi\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\",\"@xmlns:xsd\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\",\"soap12:Body\":{\"ProcessRequestResponse\":{\"@xmlns\":\"http://localhost/MeetingBrokerServices\",\"ProcessRequestResult\":{\"StatusCode\":\"None or PAR or PNE or PWE or NPE or FSR or NAC or      TF\",\"Success\":\"boolean\",\"Errors\":{\"Error\":[{\"Code\":\"int\",\"ErrorText\":\"string\",\"ErrorType\":\"None or Critical or Non_Critical\",\"Severity\":\"Warning or Error\"},{\"Code\":\"int\",\"ErrorText\":\"string\",\"ErrorType\":\"None or Critical or Non_Critical\",\"Severity\":\"Warning or Error\"}]}}}}}}";
var result = JObject.Parse(jsonresult);
Console.WriteLine(result["soap12:Envelope"]["soap12:Body"]["ProcessRequestResponse"]["ProcessRequestResult"]["Success"]);
```

returns 'boolean' as result.
However do use DavidG's suggestion as this is obviously not very neat.

Answer (score 0):

Deserializing to a class is usually the best approach, but another alternative is [JSONPath query](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) :

```
var jo = JObject.Parse(json);
string StatusCode = (string)jo.SelectToken("$..StatusCode");
string[] ErrorCodes = jo.SelectTokens("$..Code").Select(t => (string)t).ToArray();
```